# Android Studio: Create a for-loop for strings

Tags: java, android, loops

Ok so im working on a table where i get everything needed from my shared preferences, save them in Strings and then set text in the single rows of the table. Its working but the thing is: 
I feel like this would be possible with way less code if i just used a foor loop. Also this would make it possible to add and delete rows if i want to. only problem i have is: i dont know how to make this for loop. i mean i would need to scroll through "e1, e2, e3, d1..." etc. Anyone of you guys have an idea?

Here is the code:

```
   e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e1);
         e2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e2);
         e3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e3);

         d1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d1);
         d2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d2);
         d3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d3);

         t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
         t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
         t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);

         n1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n1);
         n2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n2);
         n3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n3);


        //shared preferences 
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();


        //first row
        String event1 = mPreferences.getString("event", "");
        String date1 = mPreferences.getString("date", "");
        String time1 = mPreferences.getString("time","");
        String name1 = mPreferences.getString("name","");

        //second row
        String event2 = mPreferences.getString("event1", "");
        String date2 = mPreferences.getString("date1", "");
        String time2 = mPreferences.getString("time1","");
        String name2 = mPreferences.getString("name1","");

        //third row
        String event3 = mPreferences.getString("event2", "");
        String date3 = mPreferences.getString("date2", "");
        String time3 = mPreferences.getString("time2","");
        String name3 = mPreferences.getString("name2","");


        //set text in the rows
        e1.setText(event1);
        d1.setText(date1);
        t1.setText(time1);
        n1.setText(name1);

        e2.setText(event2);
        d2.setText(date2);
        t2.setText(time2);
        n2.setText(name2);

        e3.setText(event3);
        d3.setText(date3);
        t3.setText(time3);
        n3.setText(name3);
```

Comment: Try to search for how to add views dynamically ...  I think that will help you .....

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Java you should rely on runtime checking. It's good practice! And when you'd want to save some space and dynamically refer to variables doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
---- dynamically refer to variables here somehow --- 
}
```

you deprive yourself of runtime checking. Thus bugs may occur.

You may save some space by doing:

```
e1.setText(mPreferences.getString("event", ""));
d1.setText(mPreferences.getString("date", ""));
t1.setText(mPreferences.getString("time",""));
n1.setText(mPreferences.getString("name",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we can do it dynamically:

Create array of string[] NamesTimes. Put all your stuff in array.

Iterate over the array in a loop with adding new fields.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    //Adding your TextViews
    for (int i = 1; i <= NamesTimes.length; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("This is content " + NamesTimes[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    } 
}
}
```